# Vertical nav bar to change to horizontal when window gets smaller, margin issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website with 4 sections.

I have a vertical navbar in section 2 that changes to fixed position, with a top:41, when the page reaches section 2.

When the window is minimized less than 480px, I have the nav changing to fixed position and vertical. Also with a top:0.

Here is the working script I am using.

```
var windowSize = $(window).width();
if (windowSize <= 479) {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    winHeight = $(window).height();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > winHeight - 0) {
            $('.nav').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.nav').css('top', '0px');
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < winHeight) {
            $('.nav').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('.nav').css('top', 'inherit');
        }
    })

} else {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    winHeight = $(window).height();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > winHeight - 41) {
            $('.nav').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.nav').css('top', '41px');
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < winHeight) {
            $('.nav').css('position', 'absolute');
            $('.nav').css('top', 'inherit');
        }
    });
}
```

The site works fine when loaded from a window less than 480px.

The issue I am having is that when loaded at a size greater than 480px and then minimized to a size less than 480px, the margin doesn't change. The .nav changes to horizontal in css, but the script doesn't change the top position unless page is refreshed.

There is still a 41px gap.

Anyone know a way I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just refresh the page if the window is resized smaller than 480px.

Add this code..

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if( $(this).width() < 480 ) {
       this.location.reload(false);
    }
});
```

This should make your other script run again and all should be well.

Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/0rwxx0uo/

Comment: The page stopped loading at that point when passed through that if statement.

Comment: What do you mean it stopped loading?  Here is a fiddle with it working http://jsfiddle.net/0rwxx0uo/

Comment: Scratch that, error on my end.That worked! Thanks a ton. I'll have to read up on location reload. Thanks again, really appreciate it.